# Bash script, pid of xterm process

Tags: bash

I have a small problem. In bash scripting i need to run an xterm who do some things like this.

xterm -e "(time ./program.exe 127.0.0.1) 2> out.txt"

How can i say the pid of this process?

I need to wait who it finisced for write the output and merge with another fine.

Thank so much to all!!

Answer (score 3):

Basically you start the process in the background by adding & to the end of your command, get the last started pid with $! and wait on the process to complete with wait. So, something like:

```
xterm -e "(time ./program.exe 127.0.0.1) 2> out.txt" &
pid=$!
wait $pid
```

should work.

Comment: Yes it work thanks. But how can i wait who this process end before run after command?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NikM The code above wiil run your command(first line), get the process id(the second line), and wait on the third line until your command finishes. So, whatever you do after the wait will not be executed until after your process completes. ;)

Comment: @vdbuilder How can i get the exit status of the background process??

Comment: @funtime you can print the exit status after the wait with: echo $?

Comment: @vdbuilder How do you get the pid of the process running inside the xterm window? For some reason killing the xterm process with SIGINT does not send SIGINT to the child process.